# how to disable http(s) access to my app running on GAE

Tags: google-app-engine

I want to disable web based access to my app to me or anybody.
I have some cron jobs running. That is all I want.

Comment: Can't you just display a page like "keep on going, there's nothing to see here"? If you don't have your own IP I don't think google will disable http/https for you since all other users of the IP would also be disabled.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Require admin for all handlers.

For Python, http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig.html#Requiring_Login_or_Administrator_Status

For Java, http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/webxml.html#Security_and_Authentication